# JS: calling a function mulltiple times dynamicly

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to write a small function to call other functions a specified number of times.

I've managed to do so, but what would be the best way to specify the parameters of said function?

```
var doTimes = function (times, fn, params) {
    for (i=0; i<times; i++) {
        fn(params);
    }
}
```

As it is, i'm only able to get just one parameter in, like:

```
doTimes( 3, fn, param );
```

Would be the same as writing:

```
fn(param); fn(param); fn(param);
```

But what if I wanted to go

```
fn(param1,param2,param3);
```

Without writing that 3 times, is that possible?

Comment: maybe you can make 'params' as object, on function you access it params.property

Comment: you mean like, `fn(param1, param2); fn(param1,2); fn(param1,param2)`?

Comment: @alKamili Yes, the answer from Daniel Imms worked like a charm.

Comment: @Ricky I thought of that. But I'm a bit of a noob on JS so I wasn't sure the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very useful and powerful method is to use the `.apply()` method for functions in javascript. The `.apply()` method allows you to pass an array which it will rearrange into multiple arguments. So basically you can do this:

```
function doTimes (times, fn, paramsArray) {
    for (i=0; i<times; i++) {
        fn.apply(null,paramsArray);
    }
}
```

Note: the `null` argument specifies what the `this` keyword points to in the function being called. If it's not important set it to anything (null in this case). If it is important set it to the object that `this` should refer to.

Read up the documentation of call and apply:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: If paramsArray is not defined it will return undefined, so I should check if it is undefined and in that case only run `fn.apply(null);`.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary. In the browsers I tested they all treat undefined the same as `fn.apply(null)`. But I think it's good practice to check it anyway.

Comment: OK, just checked the spec. It says that null or undefined will be treated by `.apply()` as no arguments. So you don't need to check and can silently pass undefined to apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arguments` to get all of the arguments passed in to a function call.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/w4yZh/)

```
var doTimes = function (times, fn) {
    for (i=0; i<times; i++) {
        fn(arguments[2], arguments[3], arguments[4]);
    }
}

function test(a, b, c) {
    alert(a + '\n' + b + '\n' + c);
}

doTimes(2, test, 1, 2, 3);
```

Note that `arguments` is just an array so you can test how many there are using `arguments.length`.